# Не отображается SettingsActivity

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Создавал на основе макета из AS. Код самой активности:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_open_drawer, R.string.nav_close_drawer);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences);
    }
}

public void startWordsActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void startProgressActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgressActivity.class);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void startSettingActivity(View view){
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}}
```

Код XML разметки:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/notifications_title">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            app:key="notifications"
            app:title="@string/notifications_text" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/languages_title">
        <ListPreference
            app:title="@string/languages_title"
            app:key="languages"
            app:entries="@array/languages"
            app:entryValues="@array/languagesValues">
        </ListPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/other_title">
        <Preference
            app:title="@string/other_text">
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

При запуске активности не появляется разметка, т.е просто белый фон, при этом остальные функции активности (выпадающее меню, слушатели т.д) работают исправно. Буду рад любой помощи
P.S. Разметка активности:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку активити. Возможно у вас там что-то не так. В остальном проблем в коде не видно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил разметку активити

Comment: Вроде бы нормально всё в активити. ПОпробуйте `setPreferencesFromResource` вместо `addPreferencesFromResource` использовать во фрагменте